# How do I apply an image material and get sides to line up with top face with the same scale

Tags: uv

I have a single mesh and an image of brown timber planking (with 'pretend' gaps between the boards).
How do I UV unwrap my mesh so that the 'pretend gaps' between the planks line up on the sides of the mesh with the top of the mesh and the scales on each side match.
Here is an image which shows the 'gaps' don't line up.
I'm not concerned that the grain of the timber will be incorrect for the edge.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You may just align the UV map parts. Do you need explaination about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the UVs, first select the top face and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Clear Seam* so that the sides are connected to this top face:

[image]

Then in the UV Editor, rotate and scale up the UV faces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots. I did notice that when I did the original unwrap, the 'sides' of the mesh were not as 'long' as the top face and wondered if there was an easy method to ensure that during the unwrap the sides of the mesh would be the same (length) as the the adjoining top/bottom faces without having to scale the sides to match the adjacent sides of the top face. While waiting for a response I scaled those sides to match the length of the adjacent edge of the top face and did that manually and using only my eye to determine if they matched. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: I assumed that you mention 'clear seam' as I had already 'marked seam'. When doing this unwrap (for the first time)  should I select the mesh, edit mode, clear seam, and not press U twice but go straight to UVedit?

Comment: Select the top face, press U > Clear Seam, then select all and press U > Unwrap, it should work

Comment: Thanks again. That worked. HOWEVER is that the method for where my blender file was as uploaded ie after I had tried unsuccessfully to unwrap with all faces the same length and the seams marked? If starting with a new mesh, scaled, image material assigned, I would normally go to edit mode, ctrl A  Mark seams  press U  > Unwrap and then go to the UV editor.

Comment: Added later    Yes I started the 'exercise' again (from an empty screen) , adding a mesh cube, re-scaling it to the size I wanted (27m x 2.5m x 0.05m), scaled it then applied the same material and then attempted to unwrap it so that the sides displayed in the UV editor the same length as the top and no matter what method I tried I could not get the sides to display the same length as the top.